# Drag a windows that has no title bar and Alt-Space doesn't work

Tags: windows-7

Can this be done on Windows 7? On Ubuntu, I simply alt-click the window I wish to drag. But this seem impossible on Windows.

Comment: By the way thanks for asking this question due to you  also discovered a new software

Comment: @subanki - I completely agree, this is a great question and fantastic subsequent answer. If you like his question, you should vote it up! It would be nice to see a way built-in to Windows, but I sort of doubt that exists, so this is quite handy.

Comment: [Use ALT to move windows in Windows like in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/103473/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use ALT to move windows in Windows like in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/103473/use-alt-to-move-windows-in-windows-like-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[AltWindowDrag AutoHotkey Script & Executable](http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/AltWindowDrag.zip)**

This is where I found it http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/get-the-linux-altwindow-drag-functionality-in-windows/