# ALT + Left Click to Drag and ALT + Right Click to resize windows on Windows?

Tags: windows, window-manager

Coming from Linux, I really miss some features of window manager like xfwm, etc...

One thing I got used to was to be able to drag or resize a window while holding the ALT key.

Is there such a tool on Windows?

Thanks,

Comment: Yeah... Just click and drag any corner...

Comment: I use Feewhee, nice little windows utility, welcome to the Dark Side...http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/08/16/feewhee-lets-you-instantly-resize-windows-and-make-them-transpar/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out this amazing program that does exactly what you're looking for:

- [Alt Drag for Windows](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=853371)

This keeps me sane when I have to use Windows...

Comment: It's pretty crappy in Windows 10 tho. They need to update it.

Comment: I don't understand why Windows and OSX don't have it by default.

Comment: Because alt+click in Windows may have special meaning and can be hooked by the app. Personally I don't see any much improvements using it. Most of the time I maximizes the apps, even on Linux. Therefore I rarely resize any windows. Why do you want a narrow terminal window and then have long lines wrapped around. In some cases snapping windows using windows+left/right is better

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - We all have different ways of using windows. I use this tool constantly and almost never maximize windows.

Comment: Just FYI... As of 2021-02-26, I see that there is a fork of this tool that looks to be more stable for Windows 10 (I haven't tried it, just reading the docs) at https://github.com/RamonUnch/AltDrag.  I'm still looking because I want to find something that is _built in_ to Windows 10