# Dragging Windows 10 window anywhere

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way in Windows 10 to drag a window by clicking anywhere on it? In Linux it's possible to do this by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>? I'm used to this from Linux and really like that feature. It seems I can only drag a Windows window by the title bar. Is there a remedy to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use ALT to move windows in Windows like in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/103473/241386)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/) for Windows 10, or [AltSnap](https://github.com/RamonUnch/AltSnap) an active fork. It's free, was an instant setup/download.

I'm coming from an Ubuntu development environment and I had the same frustration(s) with Windows so far, it does exactly what I wanted and more!

Not only can you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to immediately grab and drag/drop a window, but you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and double click to maximize, if you need to snap to the shared edge in a dual monitor setup you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while holding alt to force the window to stay on the current monitor and more.

> ## What is AltDrag?
>
> AltDrag gives you the ability to move and resize windows in a new way. After starting AltDrag, you can simply hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and then click and drag any window.
>
> This behavior already exists in Linux and other operating systems, and AltDrag was made with the mission to copy that behavior to the Windows platform, and then to further expand it with new intuitive functionality.
>
> You can use AltDrag in many ways. Here are some examples:
>
> - Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, then drag windows with the left mouse button.
> - Use the right mouse button to resize windows. It will resize from the corner or edge you grab closest to.
> - Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to snap to other windows. You can enable automatic snapping in the options.
> - If you have automatic snapping enabled, you can hit the <kbd>Space</kbd> key to temporarily disable it.
> - You can scroll inactive windows with the mouse wheel. If you hold down the Shift key while doing this, it will scroll the window horizontally (some programs does not support this).
> - If you have trouble moving a window, it might be because it's an elevated program (administrator privileges). To move it, you must run AltDrag with administrator privileges too. There is a button in the options to do this.
> - Windows are not brought to the front by default, hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to bring a window to the front. You can change this in the options.
> - Double-click to maximize windows. Double-click with the right mouse button to move it to a corner or side (which one depends on where you double-click).
> - If you drag a window to an edge or corner of the monitor, it will resize to occupy that space. In Windows-speak, this is called Aero Snap.
> - You can configure Alt-scrolling to do cool things such as: scroll through open windows, changing the volume, changing transparency. When changing the volume of transparency, you can hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to change it in smaller steps.
> - You can enable MDI support in the options.
> - Multi-monitor support! You can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging to trap the window within the current monitor. This is particularly useful if you want to Aero Snap at edges between monitors.
> - If you move a maximized window from one monitor to another, the window will automatically be maximized on arrival. You can hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to restore it without needing to release the mouse button.
> - AltDrag is tested on Windows XP, 7, 8, 8.1 and 10.

The guy accepts donations and it was definitely worth the price of a coffee to me

Comment: Excellent this works GREAT. Highly recommended! Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: I noticed there is a paid application in the Windows Store that says it is the Reincarnation of AltDrag. It is not necessary to pay for the store version as AltDrag works just fine.

Comment: I had what I assume is hidpi issues with AltDrag (wrong window is being dragged)

Comment: Note: Windows versions below 10 do not have native support for scrolling within inactive windows. While AltDrag does give you this option, it seems to poll the scrolling and can block / delay scroll inputs during higher loads, as well as make the system less responsive during these situations.

Comment: Wow AltDrag or AltSnap! This is the way :'D Thank you!
And latest AltDrag update was August 2023 :'o

Answer (score 3):

Further Googling found an Autohotkey [script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/EasyWindowDrag.htm) which allows for Capslock+click to work like that. Not the same but close enough.

Comment: A modified version of this script uses alt instead of caps lock: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/get-the-linux-altwindow-drag-functionality-in-windows/

Comment: And even better is this one which does moving as well as resizing using Alt+RightClick: https://autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/EasyWindowDrag_(KDE).htm

Comment: @MD004 Yes, this is the best option! You really should post it as an answer though, I was lucky I read your comment.

Answer (score 3):

There is [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/) which says is [configurable](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/doc/hotkeys.html) to use the Super/Windows Key.

It is also available through chocolatey with:

```
choco install altdrag
```

I use it since years and never failed me.

Answer (score 2):

AltDrag is an impressive little piece of software, but is not actively maintained and has unresolved issues with High DPI displays, which results in display bugs when moving windows between monitors. There is an active fork [RamonUnch/AltSnap](https://github.com/RamonUnch/AltSnap) that fixes several bugs, and adds several new features such as: controlling opacity of windows; improved snapping; scroll controls; window layouts; keyboard shortcuts etc.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `AltSnap`.

Answer (score 0):

Had good experience with WS Grid+. Supports alt dragging, hidpi and quick window positioning and resizing and a bunch more window management features. https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NBZ8NL2F408?hl=en-US

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).