# How to Adjust Off-Screen Space in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, display-settings

On a regular Windows screen, I can move programs off-screen but to a different extent based on the direction: To the bottom (south) I can move them very far so that complete windows almost disappear; to the left (west) there is not much space and to the right (east) there is a bit more space than on the left but less than to the bottom. To the top there is almost no space to move a window off-screen.

I would like to make more space at the top of the screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting to change how far you can drag a window off-screen.

When you move the mouse cursor, it will always stay on your screen unless you have another monitor attached, then you can move the mouse off-screen into the other monitor. When you drag a window on the titlebar, you are still limited to how far you can drag the screen as at some point the mouse cursor will hit the border of your screen and stop.

It is this limitation that you are facing, not "hidden zones" for moving a window around.

There is software out there that allow you to drag a window from any part of its window that is not a button which will allow you to move a window further off-screen than normal, which is a way to get what you want. An alternative is to use a second monitor and position it in the space you want the window to be moved to, so you can position it the way you want.

A third option is to script the move of the window so you give absolute values. The downside of the last method is, that if you make a script error, you may move the window off-screen to a location it hard to get it back to the normal screen. For the 3rd option, I recommend Auto-Hotkey.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know an example of such a program or the general name of these programs, which allow to drag a window from any part of its window? I'm having difficulties finding appropriate programs.

Comment: Many "window managing" programs add this as a feature. I use Actual Tools Window Manager (paid) and it has this, but I'm sure there are free alternatives available too.

Comment: A quick search lead me to: Alt-Drag: https://superuser.com/questions/1205212/dragging-windows-10-window-anywhere