# Resizing and moving an application window using keyboard hotkey and mouse

Tags: windows-10, gui

Is there a way in Windows 10, to resize an application window by holding some hotkey (e.g. `ALT`) then click and drag - as is possible in X11 for Linux?

Example of resizing in KDE here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/i1bm2i/kde_tip_resize_window_with_a_mouse_key_combo/

Comment: look at the options under the Alt+Space menu. all windows windows will react to that chord, and usually provide options for moving the window or affecting its size.

Comment: I am not looking for a way to control window size or location with keyboard-only @FrankThomas,. I am looking for way to quickly control windows with combination of keyboard and mouse. See the link - that feature enables quick and wonderful agility when organizing one's app windows.

Comment: You just  drag the window, no hotkeys or modifier needed. Size drag border, position drag titlebar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dragging Windows 10 window anywhere](https://superuser.com/questions/1205212/dragging-windows-10-window-anywhere)

Comment: not _really_. @Anaksunaman. But in the context of your updated answer it is. 
i.e. "It's simply not possible w/o third-party sw", containing a link to such software.

Answer (score 0):

This is a built-in feature in many Windows applications.

That is, simply move the cursor to the edge of a window (you'll know when the cursor is in the correct position because it will turn into a double-headed arrow), then left-click and drag to resize.

If you move the cursor to a corner, the cursor will be a diagonal double-headed arrow, and you can resize in both directions at once. Otherwise, it'll be a horizontal or vertical one, and resizing is in one direction only.

As a caveat, however, be aware that some applications may not allow resizing of their windows (though this is arguably uncommon).

---

Since it appears you want the exact same functionality, stroke for stroke, this [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1205212/dragging-windows-10-window-anywhere) may be of interest. The top answer is for a program called [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/), which appears to do what you want (hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click/drag anywhere in a window to resize it).

Comment: When having that amount of reputation I guess you are free to actively get rid of some. I am pretty sure you guys never had a laptop with small screen or used RDP or alike.
Situations where using mouse is generally awful.

Comment: Windows doesn't do what you want natively. You need third-party software . I have updated my answer to include a link to software that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the App [AltSnap](https://github.com/RamonUnch/AltSnap/releases), it will do this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1230202)