# How do I remove/relocate/customize buttons in the title bar?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I'm on a 13" laptop with Win10 and Office 365. My MS Word usually opens in a non-fullscreen window, and I find it quite annoying that if I want to drag the window anywhere (e.g. into the side of my screen for split-screen mode), I have to click a specific miniscule region in the middle of the title bar (e.g. right of the "S...") to avoid triggering all the buttons inside. Other Office programs have this too, but it annoys me most in Word. Is there any way for me to adjust the size/number/location of buttons inside the title bar (e.g. moving them to the ribbon could suffice) or otherwise customize it so that the window is easier to click/drag?

Related questions that appeared while writing my question single out the username, which I understand needs to display for one's Office to be active; however, I am not specifically allergic to this part of the title bar (though if it can still be removed long-term, I would like to hear how).

[image]

Comment: You can move easily by clicking anywhere with Alt-Drag: [Use ALT to move windows in Windows like in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/103473/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the Title Bar is not subject to easy customization an Microsoft does change what is displayed, where, from time to time, without notice.

### However, in Windows systems, you can change or move the Quick Action Toolbar (QAT) portion to below the Ribbon.

Click on the Dropdown menu for the QAT. At the bottom you will find the command to reposition the QAT to under the Ribbon. It will then appear between the Ribbon and the Ruler.

You can also, under that drop-down add or subtract items from the Quick Action Toolbar.

[image: amended screenshot]

Here is my webpage on [Modifying the QAT](http://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm) if you need more.

### You can also click on the document's name to drag the window.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the titlebar, ribbon, and QAT displayed with the QAT below the Ribbon. As you can see, moving the QAT provides a lot of room (and also allows for much more room on the QAT).

[image: screenshot]